# Mocking Datasets with Moq

Tags: moq

I'm trying to get started with Moq and having trouble finding any good resources to do what I need.

I have a Data Interface class that has a Get method which returns a Dataset via Stored Procedure. This is the way the code was written and I can't change it at the moment so it has to be done this way.

I want to test this class by Mocking the Dataset and returning data so I don't have to actually make a database call.

Is anyone doing this and if so where is a good place to get started doing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a database connection to fill in a DataSet. You can mock it like this:

```
IDataInterface di = new Mock<IDataInterface>();
DataSet mockDataSet = CreateMockDataSet();
di.Expect(x => x.Get()).Returns(mockDataSet);
something.UseDataInterface(di.Object);
```

Filling in a mock DataSet is quite painful, though. If I'm doing this, I generally put a facade interface in front of the returned DataSet, which is easier to mock. Or I change the code to use a DataTable, which is easier to fill in.

Alternatively, use an embedded database, such as SQLite or SQL Server CE, for your unit tests.

Comment: um... so what does CreateMockDataSet() do? I thought that was the question

Comment: Good point. I believe that the OP thought they needed to mock the interface of `DataSet`, and my answer points out that this is not needed. `CreateMockDataSet()` would just create a bunch of `DataTable` instances and put them in the `DataSet` as if they'd been returned from the real database.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced above problem and came up with this solution. I am sharing it because I was not able to find anything on google for this:

```
[TestCategory("GetDataSet")]
[TestMethod]
public void GetDataSet_ValidCall_ShouldPass()
{
    // Arrange

    var dataSet = Builder<DataSet>.CreateNew().Build();

    DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
    table1.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    table1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    table1.Rows.Add("1", "Name1");

    DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
    table2.Columns.Add("More", typeof(bool));
    table2.Rows.Add(false);    

    dataSet.Tables.Add(table1);
    dataSet.Tables.Add(table2);

    objectWhichHaveProcMethod.Setup(elem => elem.ExecuteProcAndGetDataSet("YourSprocName", It.IsAny<SqlParameter>(), It.IsAny<SqlParameter>())).Returns(dataSet);

    // Act
    var response = dataInterfaceClass.Get();

    // Assert  
    Assert.AreNotEqual(response, null);
}
```