# problem in nunit testcases

Tags: c#, .net

i m writing unit testcases for a class,

I want to create a db file in setup 
make the testcase to use it
and delete the file in teardown

the problem is the time taken to copy is not predicted
and sometimes the teardown cannot able to delete the file

help me please..

code in setup 
has File.Copy to copy the file

in teardown 
it has File.Delete to delete the file

Comment: It's probably not the copy time that's causing the issue, but that the data access code still has the file open. I've only done this with .mdf files, so I can't say what will work for .mdb files. As Dve mentioned, this is going down a road of pain.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of DB are you creating? Can it not be created in memory?

Comment: I think you maybe attacking the problem from the wrong angle.
You would be best either:
- scripting your db and creating an in memory version & running tests against that. 
- Mocking your data access classes and testing against them..

Maybe this post might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579075/mocking-datasets-with-moq